# Estimation of Lévy measure of ID distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Suppose that the positive random variable $X$ is infinitely divisible and supported on $\mathbb R_+$. Due to Lévy-Khintchine, its moment generating function then writes :

$$M(t) = \mathbb E\left(e^{tX}\right) = \exp\left\{\int_{\mathbb R_+} \left(e^{ty}-1\right)L(dy)\right\}.$$

**Question:** Is there a way, from a $n$-sample $X_1,...X_n$ of i.i.d. random variables, to estimate the (non-negative) Lévy measure $L$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is done in estimation of regression or pdf, you can parametrize the problem -- say by assuming that
$$\frac{L(dy)}{dy}=\sum_{j=1}^k c_j g_j(y),$$
where the $g_j$'s are known nonnegative functions and the $c_j$'s are unknown nonnegative parameters. For instance, if you choose your $g_j$'s to be the indicators of finite intervals or truncated normal densities (so that
$$g_j(y)=\frac1{b_j\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-(y-a_j)^2/(2b_j^2)}$$
for some real $a_j$'s and some positive real $b_j$'s), then you can evaluate $\int_{\mathbb R_+} \left(e^{ty}-1\right)L(dy)$ explicitly. Then your moment generating function (mgf) will be explicitly determined by the $k$-tuple $c:=(c_1,\dots,c_k)$ of the parameters: $M=M_c$.

Then you can fit the parametric mgf $M_c(t)$ to the
empirical mgf
$$\hat M(t):=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n e^{tX_i}$$
to the true mgf $M(t)$ --- say, by minimizing
$$\int_{\mathbb R}(M_c(t)-\hat M(t))^2 w(t)\,dt$$
in $c=(c_1,\dots,c_k)$ for some nonnegative weight function $w$.

Comment: This is very interesting. Would it be possible to take a known class of Lévy measures as $g_j$'s ? e.g., choose each $g_j$ as the Lévy measure of a Gamma distribution w. parameters $a_j,b_j$ ?

Comment: @lrnv : Yes, you can choose each $g_j$ to be the Lévy measure of a Gamma distribution. Then you will need to choose a weight function $w$ vanishing on an interval $[1/b,\infty)$, where $b:=\max_j b_j$, to ensure that the integral to be minimized is finite.

Comment: Could you point me to some reference where I can learn these techniques to estimate Levy measures?

Comment: @PSE : I don't know such references. These were just my suggestions.